# Rails "ajax:success" call multiple times

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ujs

I'm creating a model to show user's following and follower list just like Instagram: [image: Instagram followers list]

My controller:

```
def create
    @relationship = current_user.active_relationships.new followed_id: @user.id
    if @relationship.save
      byebug
      respond_to :js
    else
      error_handle
    end
  end
```

The follow/unfollow button is a remote (ajax) form. So after it's processed, it go to create.js.erb:

```
$(".relationship-form").on("ajax:success", function(e, data, status, xhr) {
    $(this).replaceWith(
        '<%= link_to "Unfollow", relationship_path(@relationship), method: :delete, data: {disable_with: "Loading ..."}, remote: true, class: "btn btn-outline-dark common-btn btn-unfollow relationship-form" %>'
    )
});
```

My destroy.js.erb:

```
$(".relationship-form").on("ajax:success", function(e, data, status, xhr) {
    $(this).replaceWith(
        '<%= link_to "Follow", user_relationships_path(@other_user), method: :post, data: {disable_with: "Loading ..."}, remote: true, class: "btn btn-primary common-btn btn-follow relationship-form" %>'
    )
});
```

When I click follow `user A` button the first time, it run 1 time.

The problem its that if I click the follow button a second time on `user B`, it run js for the last `user A` and then run js for `user B` (2 times). If I follow `user C`, it return for `user A`, `user B` and `user C` and so on...

This is my button form:

```
<% if is_following.present? %>
    <%= link_to "Unfollow", relationship_path(is_following), method: :delete, data: {disable_with: "Loading ..."},
                remote: true, class: "btn btn-outline-dark common-btn btn-unfollow relationship-form" %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to "Follow", user_relationships_path(user), method: :post, data: {disable_with: "Loading ..."},
                remote: true, class: "btn btn-primary common-btn btn-follow relationship-form" %>
<% end %>
```

Would be so nice if I could get the "clicked" element, because I can't think a way to name a unique ID for each follow and unfollow state.

Comment: the problem doesn't seems to be in that part of the code, can you please add the event/ajax part?

Comment: add your create.js, destroy.js files also click event function too

Comment: @xploshioOn I updated my code, please have a look

Comment: the problem seems to be that you are creating new events every time the user click on the element. remove the event part on the create/destroy and just replace directly the link because on that part, you are sure that it was a success, just let the line to replace the element and not the init of the event. test it and if it solve the problem, I will create the answer

Comment: @xploshioOn No, it wont work because I have a lot of elements with the same class:

$(".relationship-form").replaceWith(...)

Call like this will make all button change :((

Comment: That complete part needs to be inside a document ready and be loaded on the first load of that page. And it will run Everytime you send the form. Just remove it from the create/destroy js because it is not necessary to init the event more than 1 time

Answer (score 0):

Turn out that I just solve it myself. Just a bit silly and dirty way.

So after controller process done, it went to js.erb file and print the result into a "display: none" div:

```
$("#relationship-result").html(
    '<%= link_to "Unfollow", relationship_path(@relationship), method: :delete, data: {disable_with: "Loading ..."}, remote: true, class: "btn btn-outline-dark common-btn btn-unfollow relationship-form" %>'
)
```

Then in `application.js`, we listen for event `ajax:success` on buttons we want. So by using this way, we don't get duplicate event listening, thanks @xploshioOn. Then grab the data and replace:

```
$(document).on("ajax:success", ".relationship-form", function(e, data, status, xhr) {
        $(this).replaceWith($("#relationship-result").html());
})
```

Notice that I use `document` because I replace some DOM here. So a little bit trick and dirty but works :v